# "Comments" Field on DisplayForm.aspx of SharePoint 2007 not getting in Code

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I have a SharePoint 2007 website where I have a DisplayForm.aspx form.

In that form I have different fields like Issue ID, Status, Assigned To, **Comments**, etc.

I wrote some code where I am fetching the values of all the above fields. Before that I tried U2U Caml Query Builder & Caml Designer to see the values.

I am not able to get the values of Comments field.

Comments are as below:

**(1-2-2013 4:45 PM) Team Member1 : I have done this Task**

**(1-2-2013 5:45 PM) Team Member2 : Well Done!!**

How can I get the above values in my code?

The code is simple and similar to fetching the data from a list (The DisplayForm.aspx shows the data from the list after all)

Comment: Could it be that the Comments field is a rich text field or multi line field? These may present special challenges when querying with code.

Comment: Yes, It is a Multi Line Text Field.

Comment: I don't do code, but others here may be able to help. You may want to post the actual code you are using to pull the values, though. Chances are that there is a mis-match between the data types in your code and the list data types. Multi-line fields are not just strings, for example.